# How can I improve this question so I can get some help with my problem

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I asked [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/190745/i-need-some-help-with-defining-a-shell-syntax) and have started building negative rep for it. I'm actually finding it very difficult to just ask for help here without upsetting someone. What am I doing wrong?

I'm happy to edit the question and to migrate it, or whatever else needs doing to bring it up to scratch. I just don't know what more I can do.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I don't get the downvote, you've already done some prior research (IPython) and were kind enough to share that research with us. But, it's only one downvote and you can just ignore it (and I "fixed" it already). The close votes are a bit more straightforward, you are essentially asking for a list of examples, which makes the question a bit unfocused and unsuitable for the Q&A format of the site. Where does it end? How can we judge which answers actually answer your question (and if we can't judge that, how can we vote?). What's the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Thank you Yannis. I'll take your points on board and try and improve the question in line with them. I'm just glad to know that it's not all bad, and what needs to be done to improve it. Cheers.

Comment: If memory serves the last revision of your self-deleted similar question was good enough. Unfortunately you deleted it before I could confirm that (I saw your comment there asking me about this but I lost the link). In newer version, "What I'd Like to Know" part is slippery. I understand your desire to get that info but it's really hard to present in a way that would repel close-votes.

Answer (score 1):

IMO: You're getting grief because it sounds like you're asking someone else to do your thinking/work for you. Googling, reading, tinkering for yourself is probably the only way to find what you want - which is, basically, an understanding of interesting shells and the way they vary.

StackOverflow and the rest, are about much more focussed questions than this.